# how to install monoDevelop on ubuntu10.10

Tags: monodevelop, ubuntu-10.10

I have install mono and now I want to install monoDevelop on ubuntu10.10.Please anyone tell me what are the steps to install and run it.

Answer (score 0):

you can install it from the **UBuntu Software Center**.

Best regards